# how to do collapse/Expand in Multi-Level List in Android...?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

// I am searching for the solution of this problem since last 3 days , but nowhere found anything useful .
     I have to create a multi-level List (Expandablelist) with collapse/Expand functionality.

for Ex :

```
         ques1:
               q1.1
               q1.2:
                    q1.1.1
          ques2:
               q2.1
               q2.2
               q2.3
```

Please help me to acheive this functionality ...Thanks a lots